# javascript function to java

Tags: javascript, java

i'm trying to convert a js function to java

```js
function keygen(code, serial) {
 code = parseInt(/([0-9-]{12})/.exec(code)[0].replace(/-/g, ''))
 return ((code + 0x26946948) ^ parseInt(serial.replace(/-/g, ''), 16)) >>> 0
}
keygen('7043-1667-03f9-f6', 'C6AD-0E40')
```

the code above return 214930807 which is correct number

but in java i did

```
private long keygens(String code) {

        int c =Integer.parseInt(code.substring(0, 12).replaceAll("[a-zA-Z-]", "").replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""))+647260488;
        String s=executeVolCommand().replaceAll("[-]", "");
     long dec=Long.parseUnsignedLong(s,16);
     System.out.print(executeVolCommand());
     return (c^dec)>>>0;
}
     public String executeVolCommand()
      {
        String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try{

          Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c", "vol").start();  
          InputStream in = pb.getInputStream();  
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
          String line;  
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            buffer.append(line + NEWLINE);  
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        String s= buffer.toString().trim();  

        String[] words = s.split(" ");

        String lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
        return lastWord;


      }
```

but i got this error

> (C:)                 vsn:-961737152 (D:)
>   vsn:1343112398 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7043166703"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   keygen.keygens(keygen.java:179)   at keygen.access$3(keygen.java:177)
>     at keygen$3.actionPerformed(keygen.java:152)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

also, if i change 7043-1667-03f9-f6 to **00**43-1667-03f9-f6 
the error disappear but ofc it will give a wrong number

---

Also, i tried to call the js file in the java code but it return 2.14930807E8

```
private String keygens(String code) throws ScriptException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException {

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // read script file
        engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:/Users/MJ/eclipse-workspace/SM_keygen2/js/keygen.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        // call function from script file
      Object s = inv.invokeFunction("keygen", code,executeVolCommand());
      System.out.println(s);
    return s.toString();
}
     public String executeVolCommand()
      {
        String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        try{

          Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c", "vol").start();  
          InputStream in = pb.getInputStream();  
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  
          String line;  
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            buffer.append(line + NEWLINE);  
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        String s= buffer.toString().trim();  

        String[] words = s.split(" ");

        String lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
        return lastWord;


      }
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: `2147483647` - the largest `int` value in Java, you try to parse `7043166703`.

Comment: @PM77-1 ok, how can i fix that ?

Comment: Make it a long?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `int c` to `long c` ? got the same problem

Comment: But are you still doing `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh yes, i changed it now,errors disappeared but i got 4509898103 instead of 214930807 that js function gives

Comment: maybe helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994783/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-in-java-and-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Long.parseLong** number of `code` and `serial`

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      // result: 214930807
      System.out.println("result: " + keygen("7043-1667-03f9-f6", "C6AD-0E40") );
    }
    private static int keygen(String code, String serial) {
      return (int)((Long.parseLong(code.substring(0,12).replaceAll("[a-zA-Z-]",""))+0x26946948)^Long.parseLong(serial.replaceAll("[-]", ""),16));
    }
}
```

[run code](https://onecompiler.com/java/3veew9sng)

Comment: Thank you very much, if possible, send me a short video or steps to mohamedjawedi93@gmail.com shows how you find out about how the license works when you used cheatengine, i'm really very interested, i spent more than 20hours without figuring it out, appreciate your help

Comment: Ok, I'll do it when I have time!

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [how to replicate javascript bit-shift, bit-wise operations in java,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515274/how-to-replicate-javascript-bit-shift-bit-wise-operations-in-java)

In Java:

Java's long type will let you get all the precision you need to replicate JavaScript bit manipulation but you need to be sure to `mask it to 32 signed bits when using >>> where the shift amount might be 0 (or a multiple of 32)`.

So, I changed

```
return (c^dec)>>>0;
```

to

```
return ((c& 0xffffffffL)^dec)>>>0;
```

and it worked like a charm.

Thank you @PM77-1 for the helpful comment and @ScaryWombat for fixing the errors